# Nagios Graphing on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I have got most of my nagios install working, the only thing I am struggling with is any of the graphing pages, e.g. when I go onto the map page you get a page not found error.

When I try and compile, half way down the messages I get this message -

GD, PNG, and/or JPEG libraries could not be located

I have read you need these library's - gd-devel, png-devel, jpeg-devel but i'm not sure what they are called under Ubuntu, if i do and  apt-get install it cant find them.

Anyone got any pointers, i'm running Ubuntu Server 10.10

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compiliation, you'll need the dev packages as the header files are included in those. You can use the interactive tool aptitude to search for package names, or use the command `apt-cache pkgnames` to list all available packages and grep your way through this list.

Generally, those packages will have names like libnpg-dev, libjpeg-dev, libgd2-xpm-dev etc.

Comment: i managed to find the missing one using apitude, for info it was zlib1g-dev i was missing